# Criar uma função no WP para quando logar ser redirecionado

Tags: php, wordpress

Preciso criar uma função no Wordpress para que quando o usuário faça login automaticamente seja redirecionado para um outro link, aqui o meu código como está:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if ($user_id == 2) { //aqui adicionamos o ID do usuário cadastrado

    function remove_menus(){

        remove_menu_page( 'index.php' ); 
        remove_menu_page( 'about.php' );
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' ); 
        remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' ); 
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );
        remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' ); 
        remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' ); 
        remove_menu_page( 'users.php' ); 
        remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' ); 
        remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' ); 
        remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=revslider' ); 
        remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=wpcf7' ); 
        remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=loco' );  
    }

//aqui é onde tento criar a função para fazer esse redirecionamento mais não funcionou
    function realocar (){
        if (isset($_POST[get_current_user_id == 2])){
            $url = 'aqui vem o link pra redirecionar';
            header("Location: $url");
        }

    }

    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus', 'realocar' );


} else {

}
```

Comment: Evite mexer diretamente no código do wordpress. Se você não souber o que está fazendo acaba quebrando o script ou perde tudo numa atualização ou pior. Tente usar um plugin,como este: https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/redirect-after-login/
Mas se tiver de mexer mesmo, então terá de adicionar um filtro em wp-login.php

Comment: @ReneFreak eu estou criando um plugin para fazer isso, caso contrário meu trabalho pode ficar perdido em alguma atualização do WP que vier ocorrer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe um filtro [(leia sobre filtros aqui)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) no WordPress chamado [`login_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect). De uma maneira bem resumida, filtros permitem que você execute certas ações em dados "eventos" que ocorrem no fluxo do WP. A própria descrição desse filtro em especial é

> The login_redirect filter is used to change the location redirected to after logging in. This could be the location set by the "redirect_to" parameter sent to the login page.

Ou seja, você pode usá-lo para redirecionar o usuário após o login. O exemplo que vem da documentação serve para direcionar os *admins* para o *dashboard*, e os usuários comuns para a página principal. Veja:

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    //is there a user to check?
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return $redirect_to;
        } else {
            return home_url();
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

A documentação ainda alerta para o fato de que a variável `$user` pode não estar disponível no momento de execução, e sugere a utilização de `global $user`. Deste modo, fazendo um caso de uso simplificado, você pode ter algo assim

```
function meu_redirect() {

    global $user;
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //usuário existe
        return "http://meusite.com";
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'meu_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

**BONUS:**

Se você estiver usando o método [`wp_login_form()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form), você pode usar o parâmetro `redirect` que ele contém.

Ainda existe o método [`wp_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/), que faz bem isso que diz. Só fique atento para usar o `exit()` no final.

Comment: muito obrigado, bem explicado, me tire uma dúvida o 3 o 10 é o ID do usuário?

Comment: [`add_filter`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) tem quatro parametros, e os dois ultimos se referem à prioridade de execução e a quantidade de argumentos, respectivamente

Comment: Entendi, agora se eu quisesse apenas que o usuário do ID 2 fosse redirecionado como ficaria esse script:

function meu_redirect() {

    global $user;
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //usuário existe
        return "http://meusite.com";
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'meu_redirect', 10, 3 );

Comment: `if(get_current_user_id() == "2") { ... } `

Comment: Apesar de sua lógica está correta Caio, e eu entendi perfeitamente, porém na prática só funcionou mesmo o próprio exemplo do wordpress que redireciona o usuário para a página principal do site, não consegui fazer o redirecionamento para uma página externa, será que estou fazendo algo errado?

Comment: @WPfan possivelmente é algum problema com relação aos parâmetros do filtro, mas não tenho certeza. Aquele `3` no final diz que o método `meu_redirect()` deveria receber até 3 parâmetros diferentes. Faça uns testes pra ver o que ocorre